# Scala list of tuples of different size zip issues?

Tags: scala

Hi my two lists as follows:

```
val a = List((1430299869,"A",4200), (1430299869,"A",0))

val b = List((1430302366,"B",4100), (1430302366,"B",4200), (1430302366,"B",5000), (1430302366,"B",27017), (1430302366,"B",80), (1430302366,"B",9300), (1430302366,"B",9200), (1430302366,"A",5000), (1430302366,"A",4200), (1430302366,"A",80), (1430302366,"A",443), (1430302366,"C",4100), (1430302366,"C",4200), (1430302366,"C",27017), (1430302366,"C",5000), (1430302366,"C",80))
```

when I used zip two lists as below :

`val c = a zip b`

it returns results as

`List(((1430299869,A,4200),(1430302366,B,4100)), ((1430299869,A,0),(1430302366,B,4200)))`

Not all lists of tuples, how can I zip all above data?

**EDIT**

expected results as combine of two lists like :

`List((1430299869,"A",4200), (1430299869,"A",0),(1430302366,"B",4100), (1430302366,"B",4200), (1430302366,"B",5000), (1430302366,"B",27017), (1430302366,"B",80), (1430302366,"B",9300), (1430302366,"B",9200), (1430302366,"A",5000), (1430302366,"A",4200), (1430302366,"A",80), (1430302366,"A",443), (1430302366,"C",4100), (1430302366,"C",4200), (1430302366,"C",27017), (1430302366,"C",5000), (1430302366,"C",80))`

**Second Edit**

I tried this :

`val d = for(((a,b,c),(d,e,f)) <- (a zip b)if(b.equals(e) && c.equals(f))) yield (d,e,f)`

but it gives empty results because of `(a zip b)` but I replaced `a zip b` as `a ++ b` then it shows following error :

> constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;

So how can I get matching tuples?

Comment: What do you expect as result?

Comment: @SergeyLagutin added expected output

Comment: I added another OP @SergeyLagutin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your 2nd edit, what you need is:

```
for { 
  (a1,b1,c) <- a    //rename extracted to a1 and b1 to avoid confusion
  (d,e,f)  <- b
  if b1.equals(e) && c.equals(f)
} yield (d,e,f)
```

Or:

```
for { 
   (a1, b1, c) <- a 
   (d, `b1`, `c`) <- b   //enclosing it in backticks avoids capture and matches against already defined values
} yield (d, b1, c)
```

Zipping won't help since you need to compare all tuples in `a` with all tuples in `b` , it seems.

Answer (score 2):

Just add one list to another:

```
a ++ b
```

Answer (score 1):

On zipping (pairing) all data in the lists, consider first a briefer input for illustrating the case,

```
val a = (1 to 2).toList
val b = (10 to 12).toList
```

Then for instance a for comprehension may convey the needs,

```
for (i <- a; j <- b) yield (i,j)
```

which delivers

```
List((1,10), (1,11), (1,12), 
     (2,10), (2,11), (2,12))
```

**Update**

From OP latest update, consider a dedicated filtering function,

```
type triplet = (Int,String,Int)

def filtering(key: triplet, xs: List[triplet]) = 
  xs.filter( v => key._2 == v._2 && key._3 == v._3 )
```

and so apply it with `flatMap`,

```
a.flatMap(filtering(_, b))
List((1430302366,A,4200))
```

One additional step is to encapsulate this in an implicit class,

```
implicit class OpsFilter(val keys: List[triplet]) extends AnyVal {
  def filtering(xs: List[triplet]) = {
    keys.flatMap ( key => xs.filter( v => key._2 == v._2 && key._3 == v._3 ))
  }
}
```

and likewise,

```
a.filtering(b)
List((1430302366,A,4200))
```

Answer (score 1):

`a zip b` creates a list of pairs of elements from a and b.

What you're most likely looking for is list concatenation, which is `a ++ b`